# Page render array for front page

Tags: theming

I need to paste full front page of Drupal site to other page. Can I get page render array for front page for example in html.tpl of not-front page? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module and enable "Display $page array" on Devel settings page (/devel/settings).

Or you can implement [hook_page_build()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/7) to get $page array:

```
YOURMODULE_page_build(&$page) {
  print_r($page);
}
```